# Is there a reduction from 2sat to bpm?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, counting, bipartite-matching, 2-sat

Given a 2SAT instance can we convert into bipartite perfect matching in parsimonious reduction?

Comment: This question is coming out of the blue. Why would you expect such a reduction to exist? Have you attempt to construct one, or to show that one cannot exist, perhaps conditional on some known hardness assumption?

Comment: 2SAT is NL complete and unambiguous BPM is UL complete and NL=UL is conjectured.

Comment: Would the existence of such a reduction imply that NL=UL?

Comment: What kind of reduction are you interested in? Logspace?

Comment: Logspace is great but I believe an uniform DLOGTIME AC0 reduction exists. It would demonstrate BPM is hard for NL which is known I think (reason the uniform DLOGTIME AC0 reduction should exist) and indeed complete for NL since checking BPM is in AC0.

Comment: What makes you believe that?

Comment: Is there a LOGSPACE reduction?

Comment: Would the existence of such a reduction imply that NL=UL? This is currently unknown.

Comment: I think it is not likely a *direct* reduction of the nature would provide NL=UL but for the reason I think a correct reduction would provide NL=UL (meaning the solution to the problem is not going to be direct).